# BASIC program on Samba share gets 'Access denied' when launching other process

Tags: windows-7, samba, synology, basic

This is the situation. We have a Synology NAS (running DSM 5.0) hosting a Windows file share called `general`. This folder's permissions are set as in the screenshot:

[image: 'general' folder Synology permissions]

This folder is used as a mapped network drive on Windows 7 (32-bit) clients (mapped as `Z:`). No authentication is needed for this share. I.e. everyone can access it.

A legacy Microsoft BASIC 7 program houses on this mapped drive. This program itself (say `PROGRAM.EXE`) functions correctly. It runs, can create files and folders, etc. No problem there.

The problem rises when the program creates a temporary file (say `INVOICE.TXT`) and then tries to launch another process, that is printing the created text file in a nice way. According to the program's developer, it uses `SHELL Z:\INVOICE.EXE` to launch this process. What the program shows when this is executed, is: `Access denied`.

The weird thing is that when I run `INVOICE.EXE` manually from Windows Explorer, all goes well (i.e. the invoice is printed).

I'd like to add that when both programs are on a local disk, or on a shared disk of another Windows host, all goes well.

I have no clue what is going wrong. What I've tried so far:

- Disabled UAC.
- Added the IP address of the Synology to Internet Explorer's trusted websites.
- When both programs are on a local disk, all works well.
- When both programs are on a share of another Windows machine, all works well.
- Ran `PROGRAM.EXE` as an administrator (this worked only after [sharing mapped drives with all users](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx)).
- Changed the permissions of the folder as shown in the screenshot. Its directory contents look like this now:

  ```
  synology> ls -l /volume1
  ...
  drwxrwxrwx   33 guest    users         4096 Oct  2 14:28 general
  ...
  ```

  All subfolders and files have the same permissions. The accompanied `synoacltool` shows this for the folder (and subfolders + files):

  ```
  synology> synoacltool -get /volume1/general
  ACL version: 1 
  Archive: has_ACL,is_support_ACL 
  Owner: [guest(user)] 
  --------------------- 
   [0] group:users:allow:r-x---a-R-c--:---n  (level:0)
   [1] everyone::allow:rwxpdDaARWcCo:fd--  (level:0)
  ```

But all without getting it to work...

Comment: Is PROGRAM.EXE able to successfully run INVOICE.EXE when the NAS is not involved? For instance, copy the programs and any necessary data files to your desktop, unmap Z:, and instead map Z: to a local partition (so the BASIC program doesn't need to be changed to call INVOICE.EXE from a location other than Z:). That might help isolate whether the NAS is contributing to the problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [disabling SMBv2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2696547) on your Windows 7 client.  Many users report problems using newer versions of SMB with legacy applications or non-Windows systems.

```
sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb10/nsi
sc.exe config mrxsmb20 start= disabled
```

Must be run as an administrator and must restart for the commands to take effect.

Comment: I would like to add that I had the Synology option 'Enable SMB2 and Large MTU' (under the control panel's file services tab) turned on. Turning this option off, also solves the problem without going by all clients.